# How to do sys.exit() with asyncio Python 3.8+/Windows 10+ without exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-3.8

I want to write such asyncio program which exists on on some problems. I should work but it generates ugly output instead of clean exit. How to do `sys.exit()` without such ugly exceptions?

Here is code:

```
import asyncio
import sys


async def main():
    sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

Result is:

```
C:\root\Python38\python.exe C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/dptr-monitoring-v2/sandbox/python/s06_asyncio/s02_exit.py
Cancelling an overlapped future failed
future: <_OverlappedFuture pending overlapped=<pending, 0x1dba46c58b0> cb=[BaseProactorEventLoop._loop_self_reading()] created at C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py:461>
source_traceback: Object created at (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/dptr-monitoring-v2/sandbox/python/s06_asyncio/s02_exit.py", line 10, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 47, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 599, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 316, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 567, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1847, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 769, in _loop_self_reading
    f = self._proactor.recv(self._ssock, 4096)
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 461, in recv
    return self._register(ov, conn, finish_recv)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 599, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 316, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 567, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1847, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/dptr-monitoring-v2/sandbox/python/s06_asyncio/s02_exit.py", line 6, in main
    exit()
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\_sitebuiltins.py", line 26, in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\root\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 66, in _cancel_overlapped
    self._ov.cancel()
OSError: [WinError 6] Nieprawidłowe dojście

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Should be:

`Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: If the problem is only output string, you can catch it or you can change ``sys.stderr``.

Comment: It is not problem with string. I want to do sys.exit(2) but not produce not need messages. I want to do if graceful.

Comment: Just a guess: You are trying to terminate the program from a thread, but with the main program still running.  Change main() to watch for a flag.  When the flag appears, return from the thread normally and then do the exit() in the main thread after all sub-threads have exited normally.

Comment: It is some method which will work if you can change program. What if exit is from standard library for example argparse?

Answer (score 1):

Very late response but I just had the same problem (with argparse as in the comments above).   Not sure whether this is an acceptable solution but I solved it by awaiting in the main() routine as follows:

```
import asyncio
import sys


async def main():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this was caused by [bpo-39010](https://bugs.python.org/issue39010). This was fixed in [Python 3.8.6](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/changelog.html#id30) released in September 2020, and [Python 3.9.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html#id29).

This particular example doesn't appear in the bug report, but I was able to confirm that the problem in the question reproduces in Python 3.8.1 and Python 3.8.5, but not Python 3.8.6 nor Python 3.9.1.

It also didn't reproduce in Python 3.7.8, even if I add

```
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.ProactorEventLoop())
```

as Python 3.7 used a different event loop implementation by default.